# How much of the sunshine is scattered into the space?

Tags: scattering, atmospheric-science

How much more sunshine will the earth ground receive if without the atmosphere?

Comment: A related topic would be the [Bond albedo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bond_albedo). But I think this will be difficult to answer, because when you remove Earths atmosphere, its surface will change too, which also has a big effect on how much sunlight is reflected.

Comment: There are plenty of online resources which will give you the spectral power both outside the atmosphere and at the ground.  As a **very** crude mean value, across thefull spectrum it's a total of arount 2 to 2.5 kW/m^2 outside and 1 to 1.5 kW/m^2 at the ground level.